# При выборе значения с помощью radio button, менять цвет блока, vuejs

Tags: vue.js

```
Помогите пожалуйста додумать логику приложения.
```

При клике на радио-кнопки с цветом, будет меняться цвет блока ВНЕ массива.
Если бы блок (с бордером, для отображения выбранного цвета) был внутри массива, при каждом клике на радио-кнопки, можно было бы менять значение в зависимости от `true / false`. Но что делать, если блок живет обособленно от массива?

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    colors: [{
        id: 0,
        color: 'gray-500',
        checked: false
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        color: 'red-400',
        checked: false
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        color: 'orange-200',
        checked: false
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

```css
.color {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.bigColor {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.checked {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="app" class="w-full">
    <div v-for="color in colors" :key="color.id">
      <div class="flex items-center mb-1">
        <input type="radio" name="colors" @focus="color.checked=true" @blur="color.checked=false" />
        <div :class="`bg-${color.color}`" class="color"></div>
        <span class="checked">{{color.checked}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bigColor"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    activeColor: null,
    colors: [{
        id: 0,
        color: 'gray-500',
        checked: false
      },
      {
        id: 1,
        color: 'red-400',
        checked: false
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        color: 'orange-200',
        checked: false
      }
    ]
  },
})
```

```css
.color {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.bigColor {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid;
}

.checked {
  font-size: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.6.0"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<div id="app" class="w-full">
  <div v-for="color in colors" :key="color.id">
    <div class="flex items-center mb-1">
      <input type="radio" name="colors" @change="activeColor = color.color" @focus="color.checked=true" @blur="color.checked=false" />
      <div :class="`bg-${color.color}`" class="color"></div>
      <span class="checked">{{color.checked}}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bigColor" :class="`bg-${activeColor}`"></div>
```