# Как сделать выбор/переключение между элементами на Vue.JS?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Мне нужно сделать переключение между элементами на VueJS. Я пытался сделать это сам, но у меня не получилось. Получилось сделать это только на JavaScript. Вот что получилось у меня на JS:

```js
const img = document.querySelectorAll('.img');
const img_activate = (e) => {
  img.forEach(function(el) {
    el.classList.remove('img_active');
  });
  t = event.target;
  t.classList.add('img_active');
}

for (i = 0; i < img.length; i++) {
  img[i].addEventListener('click', img_activate);
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

.app {
  display: flex;
  width: 600px;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: relative;
}

.img_active {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="app">
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="img"></div>
  <div class="img"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [При выборе значения с помощью radio button, менять цвет блока, vuejs](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1090096/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-radio-button-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%86%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0-vuejs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ты рисуешь картинки из массива, то возможно вот такой вариант:

```
<div id="#app">
  <div class="app">
     <div class="img" :class="{'img_active': item.isActive}" v-for="item in items" :key="item.id" @click="setActive(item.id)"> </div>
  </div>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    items: [
      {
        id: 1,
        isActive: true
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        isActive: false
      },
      {
        id: 3,
        isActive: false
      }
    ]
  },
  methods: {
    setActive (id) {
      this.items = this.items.map((item) => {
        if (item.id === id) {
          return {
            ...item,
            isActive: true
          }
        }else{
          return {
            ...item,
            isActive: false
          }
        }
      });
   }
  }
});
```