# переключение класса у элементов по клику vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, toggle

есть массив с тегами. Нужно по клику переключать сlass active. При этом, если мы нажимаем на тег, у которого класс active - он должен пропадать.
У меня получилось сделать перекдючение между тегами, но не получается убирать активный класс при втором нажатии на тег.

```
HTML 
            <div class="tags flex-wrap" v-if="tags">
        <span v-for="(tag, index) of tags" 
            :key="`${tag.id}`"
            :class="['mb-10', {'active': activeIndex === index}]"
            @click="activeIndex == index ? activeIndex : index">
                {{tag.name)}}
        </span>
    </div>]
    
    JS 
    export default {
name: "tag",
components: {},
props: {
},
data() {
    return {
        activeIndex: null,
        tags: [
            {id: 1, name: "lemon"},
            {id: 3, name: "apple"},
            {id: 4, name: "pear"},
            {id: 5, name: "orange"},
    ],
    }
},
}
    
    SCSS 
     .tags {
    span {
        font: normal 10px os;
        color: $darkBlue;
        background: $lightGreyBorder;
        border-radius: 14px;
        padding: 5px 20px;
        cursor: pointer;
        transition: none;
        margin-right: 20px;
        display: inline-block;


        &.active {
            color: $white;
            background: $darkBlueHover;
            pointer-events: none;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: визуально, все должно работать. Вот только эту строчку `@click="activeIndex == index ? activeIndex : index"` можно поменять на эту `@click="activeIndex = index"`

Comment: работает переключение между тегами, но не срабатывает снятие активного класса при нажатии на активный.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1090096/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-radio-button-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%86%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0-vuejs/1090110#1090110   - здесь похожая реализация. А если нет - добавьте воспроизводимый пример

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот так будет работать. Посмотрите что у вас в "клике" - там вообще какая-то чушь написана.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      activeIndex: null,
      tags: [{
          id: 1,
          name: "lemon"
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "apple"
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          name: "pear"
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          name: "orange"
        },
      ],
    }
  },
})
```

```css
span {
 background-color: red;
 user-select: none; 
}

.active {
 background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="tags flex-wrap" v-if="tags">
    <span
      v-for="(tag, index) of tags"
      @click="activeIndex = (activeIndex === index) ? null : index"
      :key="tag.id"
      :class="(activeIndex === index) ? 'active' : ''"
    >
      {{tag.name}}
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```